# Using system to extract tar

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract a directory with tar files, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
The command works on the command line but not with `system` in Perl. I really need this to work in Perl.

```
$tar_dir = "/root/updates/*.tar.bz2";
system ("for i in $tar_dir ; do tar xvfj $i; done");
```

It works on command line like this:

`for i in *.bz2 ; do tar xvfj $i; done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, you could move the loop into the Perl code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

for (glob '/root/updates/*.tar.bz2') {
    system "tar xvfj $_";
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `system "tar", "xvjf", $_` to avoid passing the filenames through the shell. (See [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for details.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you forgot to escape `$i` in the string in perl.

Try:

```
system ("for i in $tar_dir ; do tar xvfj \$i; done");
```

If you don't escape it, then it will get expanded just like `$tar_dir`. Make sure you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your perl script, it will help a bit with this sort of thing (if `$i` wasn't defined in the perl script in this case, you'd have got a message from perl telling you about the problem.)

Comment: thank you very much. Both answers worked and since you said toolic showed a better option, i will go with his :). Thanks about the reminder of using strict and warning.